# `seine` oder `seiner`?

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive

`Er hat viele seiner Kenntnisse an der Universität erworben.`

Why `seiner Kenntnisse` and not `seine Kenntnisse`?
Why I think it must be `seine`:

- According to [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=erwerben) `erwerben` needs Akkusative.
- There is no Dativ article like **mit** before **seiner**
- **Kenntnisse** ist plural so it should be `seine Kenntnisse`

Source: [Linguee dictionary](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=erwerben)

Comment: No, it definitely needs to be _seiner Kenntnisse_. No _Dative_ involved.

Comment: I do not understand why this question has been downvoted. It is clearly asked, it shows some own effort and it is dealing with a cliff learners of the German language will probably have problems with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right to claim that *erwerben* calls for accusative case, and you are also right in stating that the accusative of *seine Kenntnisse* would be *seine Kenntnisse*. *Seiner Kenntnisse* is a genitive. But this genitive is not directed by the verb. The accusative phrase demanded by the verb is not *seiner Kenntnisse*, but actually *viele seiner Kenntnisse*.

Inside this accusative phrase (*viele seiner Kenntnisse*), *seiner Kenntnisse* is a **genitivus partitivus**, a genitive which indicates a relationship of being a part of something. *viele seiner Kenntnisse* translates to *many of his skills*. So, here we are talking of a part of his skills. In German (as in Latin) the genitive case is used to express this relationship.

Other examples of genitivus partitivus in German are:

- *ein großer Teil der Gruppe* ("a big part of the group")
- *keiner meiner Freunde* (”none of my friends", none is also a part)
- *die Gesamtheit aller Menschen* ("the totality of all humans", everything is also a part)
- *zehntausend der Philister* (tenthousands of the Philistines)